# GCP Monitoring agent increasing memory usage continuously

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-monitoring

I have installed GCP monitoring and logging agent on my compute engine instance. It has increased memory consumption more than 50% from the time it was installed.
[image]

Any way to stop the memory utilization and reset back to the initial memory consumption?
I have 3.75 GB RAM, out of which more than 3 GB consumed and more than 2 GB is being consumed by this process "/opt/google-fluentd/embedded/bin/ruby -Eascii-8bit:ascii-8bit /usr/sbin/google-fluentd --log /var/log/google-fluentd/google-fluentd.log --daemon /var/run/google-fluentd/google-fluentd.pid --under-supervisor"

**Update**:

After restart google-fluentd service, it brings down memory usage. But need to know the reason of its increased memory consumption. Is it a bug in fluentd service? [image]

Comment: Can you check which version of fluent-plugin-systemd is used on VM?

Comment: @JyothiKiranmayi how can I check that? I had installed agent from console under monitoring. I can see google-fluentd version, it is: google-fluentd 1.8.6.

Comment: You can check version of fluent-plugin-systemd  using command $ /opt/google-fluentd/embedded/bin/gem list | grep fluent-plugin-systemd

Comment: @JyothiKiranmayi it is fluent-plugin-systemd (1.0.2).

Comment: Can you upgrade the version to 1.0.5 and check whether you are facing the same issue or issue got resolved?

Comment: @JyothiKiranmayi Will you be able to tell the process of its upgradation?

Comment: You can check this link : https://rubygems.org/gems/fluent-plugin-systemd/versions/1.0.5

Comment: The command given in the link was installing fluent-plugin-systemd globally, was not updating on /opt/google-fluentd/embedded/bin/gem list | grep fluent-plugin-systemd. But, I finally managed to install 1.0.5 version with this command: google-fluentd-gem install fluent-plugin-systemd -v 1.0.5. It also upgraded systemd-journal to 1.4.2. I will observe the memory for some days to see if the issue got resolved.

Comment: @JyothiKiranmayi It didn't solve memory consumption issue, its keep on increasing.

Comment: As mentioned if you are still seeing the issue, it might be the buffer output plugin issue that is still under investigation. Meanwhile you can follow the workaround which is mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it seems to be a known issue. The Logging Agent product team is still working on finding a fix for this issue. You can track [google-fluentd (monitoring service) memory usage increase](https://issuetracker.google.com/193904731) for updates.

Meanwhile the only workaround to solve this is to schedule a cron job to restart the fluentd agent periodically.

To restart the agent periodically run the following command on your instance:

```
 $ sudo service google-fluentd restart
```

Another recommendation is to check that there are not multiple Logging agent instances running on the VM (periodically).

Use ***ps -aux | grep "/usr/sbin/google-fluentd"*** to show running agent processes (there should be only two: one supervisor and one worker), and ***sudo netstat -nltp | grep :24231*** to show running processes that occupy the port. Kill older instances as seen fit.

**Edit :**

Check whether your fluent-plugin-systemd  version is upgraded to 1.0.5 by using the command:

```
$ /opt/google-fluentd/embedded/bin/gem list | grep fluent-plugin-systemd
```

If it is not upgraded to 1.0.5, you can upgrade using [fluent-plugin-systemd 1.0.5](https://rubygems.org/gems/fluent-plugin-systemd/versions/1.0.5).

If you have fluent-plugin-systemd 1.0.5 but are still seeing the issue, it might be the buffer output plugin issue that is still under investigation in https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/3401

Comment: The link you provided, is asking for credential of google insiders. I checked the port and process, its running as you stated. Will setup a CRON job until a resolution comes. Thanks for update.

Comment: Any update on this Jyothi? We are running into the same issue.

Comment: No @Arian, the issue is still under investigation, you can track [here](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/193904731). Meanwhile the only workaround to solve this is to schedule a cron job to restart the fluentd agent periodically as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Great, thanks for confirming. Would you recommend to migrate to the new Ops Agent to fix this problem?

Comment: Yes @Arian, you can either migrate to new Ops Agent or you can schedule a cron job to restart the fluentd agent periodically.